# Queries on arrays with timestamps

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I have documents that look like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId( "5191651568f1f6000282b81f" ),   
    "updated_at" : "2013-05-16T09:46:16.199660",   
    "activities" : [ 
      { 
        "worker_name" : "image",
        "completed_at" : "2013-05-13T21:34:59.293711" 
      }, 
      { 
        "worker_name" : "image",
        "completed_at" : "2013-05-16T07:33:22.550405" 
      }, 
      { 
       "worker_name" : "image",
      "completed_at" : "2013-05-16T07:41:47.845966" 
       }
    ] 
}
```

and I would like to find only those documents where the updated_at time is greater than the *last* activities.completed_at time (the array is in time order)

i currently have this, but it matches *any* activities[].completed_at

```
{
"activities.completed_at" : {"$gte" : "updated_at"}
}
```

thanks!

**update**

well, i have different workers, and each has its own "completed_at".

i'll have to invert activites as follows:

```
activities: { image : 
                  last : { 
                      completed_at: t3, 
                  },
                  items: [
                      {completed_at: t0},
                      {completed_at: t1},
                      {completed_at: t2},
                      {completed_at: t3},
                  ]
    }
```

and use this query:

```
{
"activities.image.last.completed_at" : {"$gte" : "updated_at"}
}
```

Comment: do i need to drop down into javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you don't know how many activities you have (it would be easy if you always had 3 activities for example with a `activities.3.completed_at` positional operator) and since there's no `$last` positional operator, the short answer is that you cannot do this efficiently.

When the activities are inserted, I would update the record's `updated_at` value (or another field). Then it becomes a trivial problem.

Comment: well, i have different workers, and each has its own "completed_at".

i'll have to invert activites as follows:

activities: { 'image' : 
                  last : { 
                      completed_at: t1, 
                  },
                  [
                  ]